# java script website best practice

Tags: javascript, web

I am building a website using the below stack. For this question, I think the software stack should not matter. I am more interested to know whether the way I am doing the project seems like a good idea or following the best practice.

```
- Twitter Bootstrap for the UI 
- CherryPy
- jQuery
```

So the way I approached the project is like the below

```
- Use the Twitter Bootstrap to create the basic layout
- I have one js file and one css file for my project
- Based upon the requirement, let say for this button I need to do something like ajax call
    - go to the js file and write like $("#id").click() and do the necessary stuff
    - write the necessary action code in python
    - Test
```

So basically, what I am doing, modifying the html file, adding the necessary code that I need in my single js file and do the python code. Seeing all this java script framework like backbone.js, require.js makes me feel that maybe I am not following the best way to do it.

In a sense, what I want to know is that assuming you have a website with few pages that does not have heavy user interaction how would you do it? Is there anything wrong the way I am approaching it? What would be best way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: depend on how big is ur code base and how your server function, for example, a backbone "app" requires your server to send data in json instead of plain html. require.js is used to solve dependencies in a nontrivial code base, if you only have 1 js file, then it is useless.

Answer (score 1):

Client side frameworks like Backbone, Angular, and Ember are built to help bring structure to heavy javascript applications. Don't get confused between a client side language like javascript (although now it can be used as a server side language to) and a server side language like C#, Python Php etc.

Most Single Page Applications consume a REST API. So all your functionality will be on the client side. Your server's primary responsibility is to push data to your client so the user can interact with it. Think of your client (written in js) and server(written in python) as two completely separate entities/apps.

If your application is not javascript heavy, I would not go with a Single Page Application and use your current listed tech stack. I would always recommend keeping your javascript structured, but you dont need a framework for this. Just follow one of the js patterns you feel most comfortable which can be listed [here](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/).

Comment: I have started reading the book, saw it linked in mozilla developer network. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Once you have finished going through the book and are wanting to use Backbone in your next project, read [this](https://github.com/addyosmani/backbone-fundamentals) book.

Comment: Just bear in mind that unless you're using Websockets, your client will _request_ data from the server. Websockets open a persistent two-way connection between client and server ,allowing each to push and pull/request data from the other, whereas without Websockets your client must _request_ data from the server, for data to be received by the client (from the server).